# What does an arrow under a sigma mean?

Tags: notation, neural-networks

In sigma notation, what does it mean when an arrow is used underneath? In particular, in this equation:

$$y_k = f_k\left(\alpha_k + \sum_{j \to k}w_{jk}f_j\left(\alpha_j + \sum_{i \to j}w_{ij}x_i \right)\right)$$

This formula is used to describe a three-layer [artificial neural network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network) in machine learning. It’s taken from page 143 of *[Pattern Recognition and Neural Networks](https://books.google.ca/books?id=2SzT2p8vP1oC&pg=PA143&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false)* by Brian D. Ripley.

Comment: Depends on the context. Where does this equation come from?

Comment: The formula is used to describe a 3 layer artificial neural network http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network in machine learning. It`s taken from page 143 of this book:  https://books.google.ca/books?id=2SzT2p8vP1oC&pg=PA143&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: In that case, I agree with Paglia's answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe $i$ and $j$ are nodes of a graph, and $w_{ij}$ is the weight associated with the edge linking $i$ and $j$ ($i \to j$).

In this case, 
$$\sum_{i\to j} w_{ij}$$ 
means "the sum over all the $i$ and $j$ such that an edge $i \to j$ exists"